# Why was the post jail seminar scene with Jordan shown from the event in Auckland, New Zealand?

Tags: the-wolf-of-wall-street

Considering this movie was largely in America, why was the post jail seminar scene shown in an event from Auckland, New Zealand? Was this a homage to kiwis or to show how far Jordan Belfort has come, by showing he does seminars in little New Zealand?

Comment: *"..to show how far Jordan Belfort has come.."*  By 'come' DYM 'run'? ;)

Comment: Haha, guess so.  It seems like this scene hit a note with the US prosecutor http://www.stuff.co.nz/entertainment/film/9600411/Auckland-scene-final-straw-for-US-prosecutor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [interview i](http://www.nbr.co.nz/opinion/five-questions-wolf-wall-street-ck)n the *National Business Review*, the original script called for the scene to be shot in Kuala Lumpur. Scorcese changed it, and Belfort contends it was a random choice. Belfort has a cameo role in the shot as the MC.  New Zealand **was** his first speaking gig after he got out of prison, making it an appropriate choice. The interviewer from NBR intimates that NZ was "being used as a dupe country. . It was a bit like 'How low has this guy fallen? He’s talking this dreary room of people in New Zealand?'"

Interestingly, NZ is also the place Kim Dotcom chose for starting over.

Comment: He was also back in Auckland NZ last month doing a couple more seminars, I don't live in Auckland so I didn't see him. Thanks just what I was looking for.